# Zlib error when installing Pillow

Tags: python, pycharm, python-imaging-library

I've been trying to download the Pillow module for Python 3.4 using PyCharm, but every time I do this I get this error:

```
ValueError: zlib is required unless explicitly disabled using --disable-zlib, aborting
```

I've also tried downloading it from the command line, but I get the same error.

Comment: Crazy question, I know: do you have zlib installed?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Also, try it from outside PyCharm, just to eliminate that as a variable.

Comment: Yep, I downloaded zlib. And i'm using windows 7 btw

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Windows 10, Python 3.

Go get a prebuilt binary :

- http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow <--I used this one
- pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/3.4.2

Install using the command found on:  pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#installing-from-wheels

> pip install SomePackage-1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

I also install the zlib binary from official site. This may or may not have contributed: http://www.zlib.net/